# C# ASP.NET MVC application freezes after adding <video> element

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have ran into a curious issue. I have site where I want to have 2 video elements. Before adding those element the site was running smooth (a.k.a. I was able to select text, click button and get redirected to different action) but after adding the 2 video elements into the `Index.cshtml` the site is unresponsive. I do not even have any source added to the videos. When I add source the video plays but the site is still unresponsive. I have preload disabled and autoload also isn't included. Here is my `Index.cshtml` and its controller if it helps.

Index.cshtml:

```
<div class="center">
    @if(ViewBag.CourtNumber == null)
    {
        <h4>Choose court number:</h4>
        @model CourtNumber
        <form class="gap" asp-action="UpdateCourt">
            <select asp-for="Number">
                @for(int i = 1; i < ViewBag.CourtOptions + 1; i++)
                {
                    <option value="@i">Court @i</option>
                }
            </select>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    }

    <div class="video-container center">
        <video preload="none" poster="IMG/NO_MEDIA.png">

        </video>
        <video preload="none" poster="IMG/NO_MEDIA.png">
            
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

Home Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Title = this.Title;
    ViewBag.CourtOptions = this.CourtOptions;

    if (Request.Cookies["court"] != null)
    {
        this.CourtNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["court"]);
    }
    
    ViewBag.CourtNumber = this.CourtNumber;
    ViewBag.CamURL = _camTools.GenerateCamURL(this.CourtNumber);

    return View();
}
```